# How to avoid Tap to Refresh

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I am using:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

To get pull to refresh.

The problem is when I open the ListView for the 1st time, it shows a top header saying:

```
Tap to Refresh
```

When I do that it shows

```
Loading
```

and gets hidden. Then after everything works fine.

How to avoid showing that initial `Tap to Refresh`  header and just show my ListView with Pull functionality alone

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is when ListView don't have sufficient items to scroll it shows TAP TO REFRESH text when ListView has sufficient items that text gets hide so your issue is your list don't have many items at first time...